# searching is not working for data in another page in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

suppose i am in the first page. so if i search a data of the first page when i am also in the first page, searching is working. but if i search a data of the second page but i am in the first page, then searching is not working. how to fix this so that i can search any data from different page in when I am in any page?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Don't **completely change** a question with an edit. It's incredibly disrespectful to the people who have answered the original question. If you have a new question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

you can sort the data by change your code:

```
 applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource= this.dataSource.filter((row)=>row[yourColumnName]===filter)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be storing your data in 2 separate components (pages).

Try moving your data and search logic to a *service* that both those components can access.

This way the search data and logic is all in the same place.